# Flex: MX + Sparks vs. MX-only components

Tags: apache-flex, flash, components, flex4

I'm playing with the video components of Flex. When starting a new project, I was able to choose between (MX only) and (MX + Sparks). When I set the project to (MX + Sparks), the only video component I find is called s:VideoPlayer and it comes skinned. When I start the project as (MX only), the only video component I find is mx:VideoDisplay and it comes with no skin. I'm not sure which one to choose.

- Is one supposed to be better or more advanced or less buggy than the other?
- Are there any compatibility differences between them? For example, do they both work in flash 9 and 10?
- **IF** the new s:VideoPlayer is better, is there a way to set the project to the new (MX + Sparks), yet still be able to custom skin it.
- Any tutorials you recommend for the new s:VideoPlayer component?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't know all the answers for you. However, Flex 4 (Spark) is still in beta and changing frequently (in nightly builds) and I'm guess it won't be ready to go until Spring (no inside info there). However, the Spark framework is nice, imho. They are not the same compatible as they're in different namespaces in the framework. Here's one article to check out:

http://www.insideria.com/2009/05/wow-video-in-flex-4-is-easy.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the mx:VideoDisplay is a simple video display component.
You have to manually create buttons to control the video being displayed.

s:VideoPlayer comes with internal buttons to control playback, volume, etc.

Like John mentioned, Flex 4 is still beta with more changes being made every day.

It does not matter if you use the spark component or the mx component as both will display the same videom the only difference is that you will have to write control code for the mx component

Comment: Also, s:VideoDisplay does not have the attachCamera()-function, if you were planning on attaching a webcam to your videoDisplay. If this is the case, you should use mx. However, you should be able to find mx:VideoDisplay in your mx + spark-project too, by importing it manually (mx.controls.VideoDisplay)